# How to get a specific class from a classlist array in a clean way?

Tags: javascript, arrays, class

I faced a problem today, i tooks me hours to just know what it is, so I had an element, this element had many classes :

```
<div id="myId" class="first second iwantthisone fourth"></div>
```

I was using a class from the list to pass it as a parameter in an other function, so to get it I was doing this :

```
 const myClass = document.getElementById('myId').classList[2];
```

Why did I choose 2 ? because when I was doing a console.log to the classList, it was giving me an array ( not regular array ) and the result was like this :

```
['first', 'second', 'iwantthisone', 'fourth']
```

So I thought I have finished, I deployed my work to a server, I went there to test if everything is okay, it was not and that's why I am here, so the problem is that the order of the items in the array changed to this :

```
['second', 'iwantthisone','first', 'fourth']
```

So my old code in longer working, I need to do this :

```
const myClass = document.getElementById('myId').classList[1];
```

Which is not practical, I need to get the class using a method like filter for array, but it seems like I can't use it because classList is not a regular as I mentionned before.

Any solution ?

ANy help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You should never need to get a class from the classlist at all. If you already know which class you want, why not just write `const myClass = 'iwantthisone';`?

Comment: what you're looking for is [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes), not class

Comment: Bergi : Well, this just an example to show you the problem I have, in reality a Have a list of li, some of them have 'linkClass service', some of them have 'linkClass service activeLink', I needto look for the ones having activeLink for example.

Comment: user120242 : How is that ? I don't think so

Comment: you want to store data on the DOM element and retrieve it.  that's what the data attributes are for, which you can access through dataset.  if you really _must_ filter on classList: `Array.prototype.filter.call(classList, fnFilter)` or `[...classList].filter(fnFilter)`, but as Bergi has said, you really shouldn't

Comment: @TaouBen "*I needto look for the ones having activeLink*" - then use [`….classList.contains('activeLink')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/contains). You don't have to care about the index.

Comment: @TaouBen Or alternatively, select your elements using a `document.querySelectorAll('li.activeLink')` selector right away

Comment: I think he's trying to do something like: `myObjWithClassNamesAsKeys[select('.someclass').className]` or post the className as an AJAX request variable, which as noted isn't what classes are really made for

Comment: Bergi : I think i have to explain the total situation to show that it does not work, I need to filter the class from the claslist array, that's my question

Comment: @TaouBen Yes, please explain the total situation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use filter as long as you converted it from array using `Array.from()`. I'm skeptical that this is what youre looking for due to the discussion in the comments but from the question alone, this is the solution.

```js
 const myClassList = document.getElementById('myId').classList;
 var classList = Array.from(myClassList).filter(word => word == "iwantthisone");
 console.log(classList);
 console.log(myClassList);
```

```html
<div id="myId" class="first second iwantthisone fourth"></div>
```

Comment: I don't think they answered the question, but your answer is the correct one for my question, I have already found a solution but marked you as correct because that is the answer to the question